# Cisco unity call manager -- personal greeting error enabled

Tags: cisco, call-manager

In Unity CM 8.6.1, one user's personal greeting settings show the Error greeting is enabled. I cannot disable it. I also cannot enable the standard greeting. Calls for this one user do not go to voice mail. The phone just keeps ringing.

I enabled the Alternate greeting to see if this would allow me to clear out the error but it did not work. How can I fix this?

Note, I am unable to enable the standard greeting. The error greeting is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I'm quite new to CUCM/CUC

I don't think you can disable/enable either the standard or error greetings...they are part of the system.  You can modify the standard greeting with whatever personal message you want though.

That said, if the calls aren't going to voicemail at all, then I believe CUCM isn't handing them off to Unity.

Look in the line properties of the user's phone as shown below:

[image: Line properties]

Make sure the appropriate choices for that user are checked.

Comment: Facepalm. All those settings were unchecked. Thank you.

Comment: Nice! (not for you...just happy I actually knew the answer since I'm learning it as I go)